# About Database first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am using a database-first approach. After I create database and tables, I am not able to select stored procedure and functions from choosing your database objects and settings in entity data model wizard.

[image]

Comment: Well - are there any stored procedures in that database you're connected to??

Comment: Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.